# Is guaranteed in a tab "SelectedIndexChanged" always triggers before "Click"?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

In my tests I see `SelectedIndexChanged` is always triggered before `Click` for the tab control.

**My question:**

Is this behavior **guaranteed** by the .NET Framework, or are there situations where the `Click` event is triggered first? That far I did not find anything stated regarding the calling order in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,cf84486a6d2fb06c) of the control TabControl.

Basically `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggered in the `WndProc` of the `TabControl`.

`OnClick` is fired in the `WndProc` of the base Control class.

The base `WndProc` is called at the end of the `WndProc` of the `TabControl` (it is the last instruction), so `SelectedIndexChanged` will always be fired before the `Click` event.

Here is the pieces of code involved:

**TabControl's WndProc**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) { 
    switch (m.Msg) {
        // Something...
        case NativeMethods.WM_REFLECT + NativeMethods.WM_NOTIFY:
            NativeMethods.NMHDR nmhdr = (NativeMethods.NMHDR) m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.NMHDR));
            switch (nmhdr.code) {
                case NativeMethods.TCN_SELCHANGE:
                    if (WmSelChange ()) // Here will fire the event {
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                        tabControlState[TABCONTROLSTATE_UISelection] = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        tabControlState[TABCONTROLSTATE_UISelection] = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    // Something...
    base.WndProc(ref m); // The Control WndProc
}
```

**Control's WndProc**

```
protected virtual void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Something...
    switch (m.Msg) {
        // Something...
        case NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONUP:
            WmMouseUp(ref m, MouseButtons.Left, 1); // Here will fire Click event
            break;
        // Something...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Up & and accepted. A good idea for the future to check the source code. Thx!